# Is there a way to check whether $f(x)=o(g(x))$ for given $f$ and $g$?

Tags: asymptotics

I would like a way to check, for two arbitrary but specified real analytic functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, whether $f(x)=o(g(x))$.

I am using "little-o notation," where $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is true if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0, \,\,\, f(x) \leqslant \epsilon \cdot g(x)$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have an example for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where this condition applies?

Comment: Look up [`AsymptoticEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticEqual)

Comment: @ Carl Woll thanks, actually it looks like that will handle big-O notation, and AsymptoticLess can handle little-o.

Comment: @eyorble $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ implies $f(x)=o(g(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another pre V11.3 method is to use the limit definition:

```
littleO[f_, g_, x_, x0_:Infinity] := PossibleZeroQ[Limit[f/g, x -> x0]]

littleO[x, x^2, x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`AsymptoticLess` has already been mentioned, but for people using versions before 11.3 or for those who are generally interested in alternative methodologies, it seems *Mathematica* can solve this directly from the definition in simple cases:

```
f[x_] := x;
g[x_] := x^2;
Resolve[ForAll[ε, ε > 0, Exists[x0, ForAll[x, x > x0, f[x] <= ε g[x]]]]]
```

> True